# Should I group all sound file definitions together? Or define some of them locally, if possible?

Tags: object-oriented, coding-style, class-design, scope

For example, suppose my application have some sound files, now I define all sound file references in a single class:

```
public class SoundHelper{
    public static Sound buttonSound=new Sound("(some url)");
    public static Sound alertSound=new Sound("(some url)");
    .
    .
    .
    public static Sound pageChangeSound=new Sound("(some url)");

    public static void play(Sound sound){
        SomeLibrary.play(sound);
    }
}

public class DetailPageController{
    public void onPageChanged(){
        SoundHelper.play(SoundHelper.pageChangeSound);
    }
}
```

Later, I found pageChangeSound is used by DetailPageController only. So my question is, should I move the definition of pageChangeSound into DetailPageController

```
public class DetailPageController{
    private static Sound pageChangeSound=new Sound("(some url)");
    public void onPageChanged(){
        SoundHelper.play(pageChangeSound);
    }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Quite often your code will have some structure that can be organized along two axes. For example, you might structure an application by feature/component/vertical, or by layer/cross-cutting concern. You may structure a class hierarchy by class or by behavior. I call this a “matrix problem” because you can read the same information by row or by column. How you organize your code affects along which axis it can be extended easily.

Here, you can organize your sounds either

- by cross-cutting concern, keeping all sounds together, or
- by controller, keeping the sound together with the code that uses this sound.

Neither approach is right or wrong. They give you a different kind of overview:

- If you organize by cross-cutting concern, you can see all sounds in your system at a glance.
- If you organize by controller, you can immediately see all the sounds your controller uses, without having to look into other classes.

And they require different kinds of effort for changes:

- If you organize by cross-cutting concern, then changing the sound of a controller or adding a new controller can require changes to the sound helper.
- If you organize by controller, then changing how you store and play sounds will require changes to all controllers.

This is just a different interpretation of each part's Single Responsibility:

- Is it the single responsibility of the sound helper to provide all sounds?
- Or is it part of the single responsibility of a controller to provide the sounds it needs?

This choice is largely a matter of personal taste and experience. But there is one strong guideline:

> Code that changes together, stays together.

What kinds of changes will your project typically see?

- If you frequently add new controllers with new sounds, keeping the sound as part of the controller might be better.
- If most of your changes to controllers do not touch the sounds, keeping the sounds separate might be better.